# Concurrent Cache Handling

Tags: c#, concurrency, httprequest

I feel like I have hit a brick wall and just can't get any further, might have been overthinking it.

I'm making a cache handling class, that gets some data from a database, checks its time, and then if it's old it will request new data from a third party API.

But I'm stuck with the concurrency. The third party API does not like too many repeating calls, thus in the unfortunate event that `Get()` gets called twice at the same time and both try to update the data, that is an unfortunate result and I would like to remove that possibility.

But I also want to be able to handle different paths while blocking others from trying to update, while one path is already fetching data.

```
public class CacheHandler : ICacheHandler
{
    private IRequester Requester;
    private ICache Cache;

    public CacheHandler()
    {
        Requester = new RequesterHttp();
        Cache = new CacheDB();
    }

    public T Get<T>(string path)
    {
        // Get data from cache
        var cacheRes = Cache.Get(path);

        // If not null, deserialize to object and compare if its time to update from third party or to return cached version
        if (cacheRes != null)
        {
            // Deserialize xml from db
            Response<T> deserialized = Xml.Deserialize<Response<T>>(cacheRes);
            // Compare xml from db cached untill with current time 
            int compare = DateTime.Compare(DateTime.UtcNow, deserialized.CachedUntil);

            // If cacheduntill is later than current time, return cached info
            if (compare <= 0)
                return deserialized.Result;
        }

        // If no cache, or its time to update current cache - Get third party xml
        var reqRes = Requester.Get(path);
        // Save it to cache
        Cache.Set(path, reqRes);

        // Desearialize
        Response<T> deserialized2 = Xml.Deserialize<Response<T>>(reqRes);

        // Return it to user
        return deserialized2.Result;
    }
}
```

But how is my question?

I suppose I could merge it all into `CacheHandler` and do pessimistic concurrency on the db, but that would ruin the idea of being able to extend in the future.

Comment: Side note: Before reinventing existing classes like [MemoryCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) consider to check out existing ones and comment why your one is so much better.

Comment: You can't really eliminate the repeated Get scenario in a way that will scale well, because to know if you're doing the get *anywhere* else at the same time, you must only have one source of record AKA one server/service running this class. Instead, you need to hope it doesn't happen and gracefully handle errors which the API may throw. As for the locking while updating, this strategy is known as active/passive caching. Serve one copy while you update the other then atomically swap the reference... Then go and repeat the work to update the passive copy. 2x the computing and memory, 0 locks.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

At the most basic level, you could wrap this call in a lock to prevent the race condition you describe:

```
public class CacheHandler : ICacheHandler
{

private IRequester Requester;
private ICache Cache;

private object syncLock = new object();


public CacheHandler()
{
    Requester = new RequesterHttp();
    Cache = new CacheDB();
}

public T Get<T>(string path)
{
    lock(syncLock)
    {
        // Get data from cache
        var cacheRes = Cache.Get(path);

        // If not null, deserialize to object and compare if its time to update from third party or to return cached version
        if (cacheRes != null)
        {
            // Deserialize xml from db
            Response<T> deserialized = Xml.Deserialize<Response<T>>(cacheRes);
            // Compare xml from db cached untill with current time 
            int compare = DateTime.Compare(DateTime.UtcNow, deserialized.CachedUntil);

            // If cacheduntill is later than current time, return cached info
            if (compare <= 0)
                return deserialized.Result;
        }

        // If no cache, or its time to update current cache - Get third party xml
        var reqRes = Requester.Get(path);
        // Save it to cache
        Cache.Set(path, reqRes);

        // Desearialize
        Response<T> deserialized2 = Xml.Deserialize<Response<T>>(reqRes);

        // Return it to user
        return deserialized2.Result;
    }
}
}
```

This is not the best strategy for speed, though, in multiple senses. Ideally, you might want to store this cache data in memory, and then persist it to the database asynchronously. In that way, your collision window will get smaller (although not entirely disappear).

I don't see a way around the lock around the method, but if you utilize the in-memory cache you would be locking for a much shorter period of time, instead of the entirety of what is going to be a slow round trip from the database (in comparison).